# PresenceChannel Sends Request To The Wrong URL And Gives 404 Error - Laravel Broadcast

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-echo

I'm running a laravel react app that utilizes `laravel-echo` and `laravel-echo-server`.
I got everything running fine at first and I even have an online instance.

But I'm having issues converting from public `Channel` to `PresenceChannel` on my local machine. It keeps giving me this error:

```
[3:37:36 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost/backoffice/public
[3:37:36 PM] - Sending auth request to: http://localhost/backoffice/public/broadcasting/auth

⚠ [3:37:37 PM] - arykq6KJQleWh_EFAACU could not be authenticated to presence-main-session.
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 634,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 623,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\backoffice\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\index.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404
```

The main issue here is the fact that my local configuration is different. I'm using:

1. Xampp
2. I'm running a Custom URL locally, not `http://localhost` but `http://backoffice.com`
3. So It still sends to `http://localhost/backoffice/public/broadcasting/auth` instead of `http://backoffice/broadcasting/auth`.
4. It's a `windows` system.

My `bootstrap.js`:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
// Have this in case you stop running your laravel echo server
if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    authEndpoint: window.location.hostname + '/broadcasting/auth',
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
  });
}
```

My `laravel-echo-server.json`:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://backoffice.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "XXXX",
            "key": "XXXXX"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {}
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

My `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [ 'web', 'auth:ad_user' ]]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

may be there Issue was due to `csrf-token`

try something like this:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
encrypted: true,
auth: {
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
}});
```

this one work for me.